# Woocommerce wpdb filter for custom product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a custom product in woocommerce. I am trying to filter my custom_product using below code but it seems the product_type of my custom_product is still 'product'. How to filter the my custom product?
E.g. below code can filter for default woocommerce variable products

```
$filtered_products = $wpdb->get_results(
    "
    SELECT * 
    FROM `" . $wpdb->prefix . "posts` 
    where (post_type='product_variation') AND post_status='publish'
    "
    );
```

But below code cannot filter the custom product type I added

```
$filtered_products = $wpdb->get_results(
    "
    SELECT * 
    FROM `" . $wpdb->prefix . "posts` 
    where (post_type='custom_product') AND post_status='publish'
    "
    );
```

Any other suggestions to filter my custom_product?

Comment: Have you already tried the SQL query in your database?

Comment: Custom product types are stored as a taxonomy. Products will always have the "product" or "product_variation" post type. To do this vis SQL you will probably need to do a complex statement that joins the terms/taxonomies. Can I ask why you need to use SQL here? There are both PHP and rest API approaches to fetching products.

Comment: @helgatheviking I am OK with any approach. Can you please point out to any other approach. Google wasnt much helpful, may be I was not searching with the right terms

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use `wc_get_products()` if you need to fetch the products via code.

```
// Get custom_product products.
$args = array(
    'type' => 'custom_product',
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
```

Source: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

To use the REST API I *think* you would send a request to this URL:

`/wp-json/wc/v3/products?type=custom_product`

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#list-all-products

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it using WP_QUERY instead of SQL query. Took help from below link
[Meta Query](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html)

Comment: Glad you solved it. Could you post the full code of your solution? It might help someone else down the road.